# Las listas anidadas dan como resultado matrices multidimensionales

Tags: numpy

No entiendo esta forma de inicializar una matriz multidimensional usando una lista de listas (Numpy):

```
np.array([range(i, i + 3) for i in [2, 4, 6]])

OUT:

array([[2, 3, 4],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

¿Como se obtienen el 3, 5, 7 y el 4, 6, 8?

Entiendo que con range(i, i+3) está definiendo que la matriz será de tres columnas, pero ¿cómo podemos entender en este código, que los valores de cada una de las dos columnas se obtienen sumando 1 al valor de la columna anterior?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La falsa apariencia de que se está sumando 1, la hacer el `range()` y los números elegidos. Lo que estás haciendo es lo siguiente:

1. Con el bucle `for` cogemos el primer número en la lista **el dos**
2. Definimos un **rango de dos a cinco** [2, 2 + 3).
3. Esto nos devuelve una lista con rango dos a cinco: [2,3,4]. **Tenemos la primera fila**

Una vez hecho esto, volvemos a repetir el mismo bucle.

El `for` nos trae el siguiente número de la lista, en este caso **el cuatro**, creamos un **rango de cuatro a siete** y nos devuelve una lista [4,5,6]. **Tenemos la segunda fila.**

Por último volveríamos a empezar el bucle con el último número **el seis** y al final obtendriamos la tercera y última fila: [6,7,8].

## Función range()

La función `range()` lo que hace es crearnos un **rango** de números. Al inicio del bucle sería un rango de [2, 5). Como apuntas, `i + 3` lo que te está dando es el número de columnas, porque si pusieras un cuatro, tendrías 4 columnas, ya que el rango de números sería en el primer caso [2,6). Y siempre en el bulce, la función range, devolvería cuatro números.